# Max element of limits

Tags: limits

If $$\lim_ {x\to a}\ f(x) = l$$ and $$\lim_ {x\to a}\ g(x) = m$$ then $$\lim_{x\to a} \max\{f, g\}(x) = \max\{l, m\}$$
Explain why the statment is true.

Comment: If there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}\to l$ and a sequence $\{b_n\}\to m$...  So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The two variable function $w(u,v)=\max(u,v)$ is continuous, and the statement of the post follows from this, although I don't know what assumptions you are allowed to use.

Answer (score 5):

$\max\{f,g\}=\dfrac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|)$ so $\max(f,g)$ is continuous.

Comment: why max{f, g} = 1/2(f+g+|f-g|)?

Comment: @user108159 If $f\ge g$ then $|f-g|=f-g$ and $\frac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|)=\frac{1}{2}(f+g+f-g)=f$. Similarly, you can check that $\frac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|)=g$ if $f<g$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Another approach using the definitions of limits can go as follows. Suppose that $l > m$. Then let $\epsilon = \frac{l-m}{2}$. Since $f(x) \to l$ and $g(x) \to m$, there is some $\delta_1 >0$ and $\delta_2 > 0$ such that if for any $x$ with $|x-a|< \delta_1$, then $|f(x)-l| < \epsilon$ and if $|x-a|< \delta_2$ then $|g(x)-m| < \epsilon$. Now, taking $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ then you should be able to argue that for any $x$ with $|x-a| < \delta$ then $\max\{f,g\}(x) = f(x)$ and therefore will converge to $l$ as $x \to a$. Can you take the the argument from here?

Comment: I am sorry, but can you help a bit more

Comment: @user108159 Can you be more specific? Where are you getting stuck and would like me to point you in the right direction?

Comment: To be honest, while I unsterstand what you are doing, I have little to no idea what is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Is your response supposed to be "proof based" or is this asking whether or not you have intuition towards *why* this is true.

Comment: The question is find out if it's true or false and then, if true, prove it. I checked on my book and I am 99% sure it's true.